# Select2 - placeholder not showed when custom template used

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I have initialized an select2:

```
$("#myInput").select2({
    ajax: {
    url: /url/to/get',
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function(params) {
        return {
            code: params.term
        };
    },
    processResults: function(data) {
        return {
            results: data
        };
    },
    cache: true
    },
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
    templateResult: formatResult,
    templateSelection: formatSelection,
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    allowClear: true,
    placeholder: 'Select data'
});
```

Unfortunately, placeholder for empty value is not show.

When remove custom template for result:

```
$("#myInput").select2({
    ajax: {
    url: /url/to/get',
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function(params) {
        return {
            code: params.term
        };
    },
    processResults: function(data) {
        return {
            results: data
        };
    },
    cache: true
    },
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    allowClear: true,
    placeholder: 'Select data'
});
```

Here are my templates:

```
function formatResult(repo) {
    if (repo == null) return "";

    if (repo.loading) return repo.brief;

    var markup = "<div class='clearfix' style='padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom: 3px; '>";
    markup += "<div style='color: black; font-size:12px; font-weight: bold; word-wrap: break-word; line-height: 0.9; margin-bottom: 4px; '>";
    markup += repo.city + "</div>";

    markup += "<div style='font-size: 9px; color: #777; margin-top: 4px;'>";
    markup += repo.postCode + ", " + repo.voivodeship;
    markup += "</div></div>";

    return markup;
}

function formatSelection(postCode) {
    if (postCode == null) return "";
    return postCode.postCode;
}
```

Should I put sth in template?

Comment: I have same problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using v4 then you will need to use `<select ></select>` and not `<input>` to bind your select2 to.

Using an input element in v4 causes some issues because input is not supported anymore. 
I believe I had similar issues and once I changed my input element to a select element everything turned out fine.

Comment: @nopeflow does it have an empty `<option></option>` to bind the placeholder to?

Comment: Hmm... that could be a problem! But why without empty option and template it works?

Comment: I don't know for sure. But I try to keep things to their spec because I've had issues when I didn't.